# TypeError: Modele_1.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, importerror

I'm new to Webpack and typescrypt, so it may be a simple error, but I'm not capable to find it.

I import my model from the main.ts file :

```js
import View from "./View/View";
import Controller from "./Controller/Controller";
import Inventaire from "./Modele/Modele";

require("tether");
require("bootstrap");

function main(): void {
    let model = new Inventaire();
    let controller = new Controller(model);
    let view = new View(controller);
}

main();
```

but when I run it I have an error in the console :

```
TypeError: Modele_1.default is not a constructor
```

model.ts :

```js
export default class Inventaire {

    private _achats: Achat[];

    constructor(achats: Achat[] = [/*default values*/]) {
        this._achats = achats;
    };
    /*...*/

}

class Achat {
    Nom: string;
    private _Quantite: number;
    Prix: number;
    Description: string;
    Poids: number;
    Photo?: string[]; //path of the image

    constructor(nom: string, prix: number, description: string, poids: number = 0, photo?: string[]) {
        this.Nom = nom;
        this.Prix = prix;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Poids = poids;
        if (photo) this.Photo = photo;
    }

}

class ModelePanier {
    Contenu: Achat[];
    Quantite: number = this.Contenu.length;

    PrixTotal(): number {
        let prix: number = 0;
        for (let achat of  this.Contenu) {
            prix += achat.Prix;
        }
        return prix;
    }
}
```

I tried to use the import with and without default, but both don't work.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, just something I noticed reading over your code: you may run into bugs later with the default `achats` value in the `Inventaire` constructor. When you use an array as a default value, the *same array instance* will be used every time--so if you construct multiple `Inventaire` instances using the default value, modifying `this._achats` will modify all those instances. An easy way around that is to provide the default value inside the constructor: `this._achats = achats || [/*default values*/]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following will definitely work:

```
export default class Inventaire {
```

And assuming the path `./Modele/Modele` is correct the following will definitely work:

```
import Inventaire from "./Modele/Modele";
```

Comment: that's what I tried, and it still give me an error. I don't know why, because Webpack compiles everything fine. here is the detail of the error if it helps : 

    TypeError: Modele_1.default is not a constructor

`"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
// import View from "./View/View";
var Controller_1 = require("./Controller/Controller");
var Modele_1 = require("./Modele/Modele");
function main() {
    var model = new Modele_1.default();
    var controller = new Controller_1.default(model);
    //let view = new View(controller);
}
main();`